# jQuery serialize inputs on form submit, but not with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter, submit

Is there no way of submitting a serialized parameter without ajax?

I want to access, like, an json encoded parameter when I process the POST from the form, something like: `$params =  json_decode($_GET['params']);`

Any ideas, besides iterating each input and append it to a hidden one that will contain all parameters in an encoded form, ?

### Update

I'm using codeigniter, so I would rather do something like

```
$search = json_decode($this->input->get('params'));
updateName($search['name']);
updateGender($search['gender']);
```

Than

```
updateName($this->input->get('name'));
updateGender($this->input->get('gender'));
```

Comment: Why bother? There's no shortage of server side libraries for processing application/x-www-form-urlencoded data (which **is** serialised, just not as JSON).

Comment: @Quentin I've updated my question, reasoning why I wan't to do so

Comment: it's pretty pointless to do that. you could use javascript to serialize and create a hidden input before the form submits. but the way you are proposing is wrong... cuz $search['name'] will throw an error if name doesnt exist while $this->input->get('name') won't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I am missing something here but you can only do a `json_decode()` on a json object/array.

`$this->input->get()` will return the whole $_GET array AS A PHP ARRAY, so you dont need to do anything JSON'ick with it to be able to use it as an array.

so would this not do what you want?

```
$search = $this->input->get();
updateName($search['name']);
updateGender($search['gender']);
```

If you want to pass it through the XSS filter first just use

```
$search = $this->input->get(NULL, TRUE);
```